# Chromium and virtual keyboard with automatic popup

Tags: touchscreen, chromium

I want to run Chromium in full screen (kiosk) on Raspbian Stretch. I have a touch screen and I need a virtual keyboard to popup when I enter a text field.

On Debian 9, I have gotten this to work successfully using matchbox-window-manager and matchbox-keyboard with the "-d" option. I've tried the same setup on Raspbian but I cannot get it to work.

I have run matchbox-keyboard in a debugger and it does not seem like it's getting the events from Chromium. Can this be solved by installing packages or is it related to how Chromium is compiled for Raspbian?

Answer (score 2):

Get this Chrome extension.
[image]
It's an onscreen keyboard, with the ability to pop-up when a text field is selected.

Just what you need.

Comment: No, I'm not affiliated with the extension. I don't even use it! But it's a common question, and this is the answer.

Comment: Thanks. I would consider this a work-around, but I would really like to know why my setup works with Debian 9 and not Raspbian. Even though the primary application is running in chromium, I sometimes need access to the OS without using a physical keyboard.

Comment: I think Raspbian is missing some gnome packages that enable accessibility features like this one. Not sure which ones you need, but if you could use a system-wide onscreen keyboard, just expect it to be there all the time.